# can i pass a string to a javascript function and use it as an attribute of an object?

Tags: javascript

i want to pass a string to a javascript function and use it as an attribute like this :

```
function object (){
   this.somevalue = 1;
   this.somevalue2 = 1;
   this.updateAttribute = function(name,value){
      this.{name} = value;
   }
}
```

can it be done ? Thank You .

Comment: You can refer to object properties like this... `object[name]` but in your case I believe `this` will refer to the function, not the object containing the function.

Comment: @Archer: The value of `this` depends on how the function is called. Since we don't know how it is called we don't know what `this` refers to.

Comment: it's called like this x = new object();
x.updateAttribute(name,value);

Comment: @Archer yes it works , Thank You :D

Comment: @FelixKling Thank You For Helping :D

Comment: @FelixKling That's exactly why it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `[]` <strike>operator</strike> bracket notation:

```
 this[name] = value;
```

Comment: FWIW, `[]` is not an operator.